# Vue.js Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')

Tags: asp.net, vue.js, typeerror

I'm trying to get list of the data.

At the backend side, I used asp.net core. I could take the data from backend side but i couldn't display on the frontend screen.

At the `v-for="personnel in personnels" :key="personnel.id"` part, there is an error.
Error is: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')"

Here the codes:

```
    <template>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header pb-0 px-3">
        <h6 class="mb-0">Personnel Informations</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body pt-4 p-3" >
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item border-0 d-flex p-4 mb-2 bg-gray-100 border-radius-lg">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column" v-for="personnel in personnels" :key="personnel.id">
               <h6 class="mb-3 text-sm"> {{personnel.name}} {{personnel.surname}} </h6>
              <span class="mb-2 text-xs">
                Title:
                <span class="text-dark font-weight-bold ms-sm-2">{{personnel.title}}</span>
              </span>
              <span class="mb-2 text-xs">
                Email Address:
                <span class="text-dark ms-sm-2 font-weight-bold">oliver@burrito.com</span>
              </span>
              <span class="text-xs">
                VAT Number:
                <span class="text-dark ms-sm-2 font-weight-bold">FRB1235476</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="ms-auto text-end">
              <a class="btn btn-link text-danger text-gradient px-3 mb-0" href="javascript:;">
                <i class="far fa-trash-alt me-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Delete
              </a>
              <a class="btn btn-link text-dark px-3 mb-0" href="javascript:;">
                <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt text-dark me-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Edit
              </a>
            </div>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
      </template>

    <script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
     name: "personnel-card",
     data() {
     return {
      personnels: []
    };
  },
     mounted() {
     this.getPersonnels();
  },
     methods: {
     async getPersonnels() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://localhost:7022/api/Personnels');
        this.personnels = response.data;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
  }
};
    </script>
```